# Photoelectric effect -

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Would there be an easily observable and measurable difference in the electric charge on a basic electroscope if I use plates made of different metals? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry Martha, I got my wires crossed earlier on the photoelectric effect on electroscopes. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a demo with a zinc plate connected to an electroscope.  Give it a negative charge and then shine a UV light on it and the charge on the electroscope drops noticeably faster than with bright visible light.  I'm not sure if any other metals are practical for this sort of demo.